# How do you set a binary value from a string variable comprised of a binary literal in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column of binary literals converted to strings that I need to relate to a table containing the same value as binary(16)

Root table string Value '2F774578C33011E880D80050569C29CA'

table value I need to join to 0x2F774578C33011E880D80050569C29CA

is there a way to convert either the root table to Binary by simply adding the 0x to the string then declaring the string a literal value for the binary? or convert the binary to the string contained in the root.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
DECLARE @jobIDBinary Binary(16) 
DECLARE @jobString Nvarchar(50) 

SET @jobIDBinary = '0x'+
(SELECT TOP (1) JobId

FROM  [Record])
```

error: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I also tried converting the other way:

```
 DECLARE @convo varchar(max) 
 SET @convo = (SELECT TOP (1)
 [BinaryJobID]
 FROM [GAPClaims].[dbo].[Record2]

 WHERE binaryjobId IS NOT NULL )
```

Results = ,]óJ¾¶‡Á§\ê€

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: why not just use convert or cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `varbinary` to `varchar`, and join on it (or relate it, as you stated).

```
declare @v varbinary(16) = 0x2F774578C33011E880D80050569C29CA
select @v, convert(varchar(256), @v,2)

declare @s varchar(256) = '2F774578C33011E880D80050569C29CA'
select @s, convert(varbinary(16),@s,2)
```

So, for you:

```
 DECLARE @convo varchar(max) 
 SET @convo = (SELECT TOP (1)
 convert(varchar(256),[BinaryJobID],2)
 FROM [GAPClaims].[dbo].[Record2]
 WHERE binaryjobId IS NOT NULL )
```

See the [Binary section in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187928(v=sql.105)) for why I used `2` in the `convert` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert string to binary:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(16), @jobString)
```

and Reverse:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), @jobBinary)
```

Comment: Thank you, but converting to varchar(max) still translated the data in the binary to character rather than the string of text contained in the binary column.  results = ,]óJ¾¶‡Á§\ê€

Comment: You need to specify the style, since 0 is the default.

Comment: @user9776216 I just didn't catch the part that you want to prepend the binary prefix. So this was only general conversion examples. Having read your question again, i see your point :)